# Insertion in Excel failed

Tags: java, excel, odbc

I tried inserting data into excel sheet using Java and ODBC, my URL is correct, the query to insert the data is executing, but the values are not inserted into excel sheet, i have made connection to commit and close. kindly help!

```
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:excelDsn;readonly=false;");
        ps = con.prepareStatement("insert into [Sheet1$](FirstName, LastName) values (?,?)");
        ps.setString(1, "AA");
        ps.setString(2, "BB");
        ps.execute();
        con.commit();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Tried with ps.executeUpdate(), now it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for [DDL statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) like `insert`,`delete` and `update` use `ps.executeUpdate();` 
As your case is to insert so replace `ps.execute();` with `ps.executeUpdate();`